# What is difference between UIModalTransitionStyle and UIModalPresentationStyle?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle, uimodaltransitionstyle

For UIViewController, we have [UIModalTransitionStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalTransitionStyle) and [UIModalPresentationStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle)

Question is what is the difference of them ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

UIModalTransitionStyle is used to specify how the modal form transitions into view.  For example, it can come in vertically, flip horizontal, or do a partial curl.

UIModalPresentationStyle is used to specified whether you want the modal form to be full screen (basically what iPhone uses) or otherwise (therefore only makes sense for iPad) as a page sheet (full height, width is the size of the portrait mode screen width), a form sheet (partial width and partial height) or current context (i.e. what the parent container uses).